# Selenium only getting last page when scraping multiple static pages to Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium, dataframe, web-scraping

```
df_results = pd.DataFrame()

#testing with the for loop instead of while because I don't want to run all pges yet, just first 4
for i in range(0,5):
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class= 'next fg-button ui-state-default']")
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
    
    # I've also tried by removing the variable
    df_results = df_results.append(pd.read_html(driver.page_source))
  
df1 = pd.concat([df_results])

#save as csv
df1.to_csv('cds.csv')
```

I'm trying to scrape through multiple pages with 1 table in each page that have the same elements. (sounds so simple when I write this....)
I'm just getting stuck trying to save each page to an empty data frame.
'''df_results''' is only getting the table rows from the last page and it's showing those same rows 5 times. So its successfully going through each page but not saving every row.
I tried appending in the loop and then I added concat outside the loop but it didn't work.

Comment: Add the URL as well from where you are scrapping data.

Comment: @Vin It's not something I want to make public, but I was able to solve it. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I had to add a sleep(10) after the ActionChains that clicks through 'next'. It was clicking through too quickly before the page loaded which is why nothing was saving in the database. Hope this helps someone else, I was searching everywhere!